# Qual é o motivo dessa atribuição IF/ELSE?

Tags: php, lógica

Porque neste código o valor `0` é atribuído ao `IF` e o valor `1` é atribuido ao `ELSE`?

```
<?php
$flipCount = 0;
do {
    $flip = rand(0,1);
    $flipCount++;
    if ($flip){
        echo "<div class=\"coin\">H</div>";
    }
    else {
        echo "<div class=\"coin\">T</div>";
    }
}
```

Levando em consideração as respostas apresentadas, então é o contrário:

> **IF** = TRUE (1) e **ELSE** = FALSE (0)

Comment: Eu tinha entendido mal sua pergunta. Tome meu +1 agora.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Em várias linguagens (Javascript e C também são assim), é comum que o `0` numérico seja tratado como equivalente a falso em desvios de fluxo (`IF`). Isso é por design.

No caso específico do PHP, ocorre uma conversão da exressão dentro dos parênteses do `IF` para um valor booleano. As seguintes expressões viram falso quando convertidas:

- o próprio booleano FALSE;
- o inteiro 0 (zero);
- o ponto flutuante 0.0 (zero);
- string vazia ("");
- a string "0";
- um array sem elementos;
- um objeto sem elementos membros (somente PHP 4);
- o tipo especial NULL (incluindo variáveis não definidas);
- o objeto SimpleXML criado de tags vazias;

Roubei essas informações da [documentação oficial](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.types.boolean.php#language.types.boolean.casting).

Comment: Muito booooommm !!! Obrigadíssimo !!!

Comment: +1 pelo link hehe estava procurando ele.

Comment: Vale salientar que esse tipo de teste pode se tornar extremamente difícil de se depurar. Jamais confie no *cast* automático do PHP. Na maioria das vezes ele é burro e intrometido. Se seu teste serve para executar algo quando outra coisa for bem sucedida, então prefira `if( $something !== FALSE )` (note o operador de comparação também por tipo).

Answer (score 6):

O php faz cast automaticamente alguns valores como: `zero`, `vazio` e `null` são convertidos em `false` logo cai no else, qualquer outro valor ex: `1`, `-1` são interpretados como `true`

Comment: Perfeito ... Ótimo e esclarecedora sua resposta.

Answer (score 2):

O valor 0 não é atribuído ao IF. O IF apenas avalia se o parâmetro que passou é verdadeiro ou falso e para fazer essa avaliação utiliza os critérios que acima foram explicados.

Então se for passado para o IF o valor de 0(zero) é avaliado como falso e o programa executa o bloco definido no ELSE, ou seja o parâmetro no IF é não verdadeiro.

Se o valor for 1, que é avaliado como verdadeiro, então o bloco dentro do IF é executado.

Totalmente como se espera que o código se comporte, não como afirma na pergunta.