# operadores || ou OR no PHP

Tags: php

Qual o melhor e como usar?

Estou a tentar executar este código por exemplo e ele não funciona

```
if(1 !== 1 || 2) {
    echo true;
}
```

ele exibe o true sendo que era pra mostrar apenas se X (no caso o 1) fosse indiferente de 1 ou 2.

Comment: Se é uma condição composta é necessario, repetir o predicado na condição. quanto ao `||` e `OR` tem diferença sim.

Comment: @rray então a forma que eu apresentei na pergunta é inválida correto?

Comment: O que vc espera é `if(1 !== 1 || 1 !== 2){ echo true;}` ?

Comment: Além do que o @rray disse (incluir o predicado na segunda parte da condição) acho que o erro é que vc tá usando o operador `||`, quando deveria estar usando o `&&`... Você quer, pelo que entendi, que escreva `true` se 1 for diferente de 1 E se 1 for diferente de 2. Não é isso : if(1 !== 1 && 1 !== 2) {
    echo true;
} ? Só pra constar, eu não negativei a pergunta...

Comment: @gustavox é isso mesmo, obrigado por me ajudar!. Sobre os negativos, bom, eles não prejudicam a mim e sim a comunidade.

Comment: Ok, mas leia com atenção a reposta do @rray, porque ela explica a razão de não estar funcionando antes e ainda dá ótimas dicas sobre o funcionamento dos operadores ( que inclusive foi muito útil pra mim... dei  +1 na resposta dele, mas agora vi que deram um negativo :/ que tbm não fui eu! obv).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O if pode ser traduzido como `se 1 não é identico a 1 OU dois(que é true)`, ao trocar as senteças pelos valores lógicos fica, `SE(falso OU verdadeira) ENTAO ...`.

A primeira parta da sentença(`1!==1`) é falsa e a segunda(apenas o `2`) é considerada verdadeira para o php, pois a linguagem trabalha com casts automaticos, ela define uma serie de valores que podem ser avaliados como `false` e qualquer coisa fora disso é `true`, como as sentenças estão conectadas através `||`(OU lógico) basta uma valor verdadeira para validar a condinção.

A diferença entre `||` e `OR` é que `OR` tem menos prioridade ou nesse caso fique esperto para resultados inesperados ou para adicionar parênteses na condição.

**Leitura recomendada**

[Lista de valores false para o PHP](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/34554/91)

[Qual a diferença entre “&&” e “||” e “and” e “or” em PHP? Qual usar?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/47886/91)

Comment: Continuo não entendendo muito bem.. No caso do código que citei mesmo com parênteses nas opções ele da `true`.

Comment: Não estou entendendo o porque de tanto negativamento, mas marquei a sua como certa, obrigado!